# Getting different answers after MPI_Accumulate

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

In the code below, I get different answers such as 1, 2, 3 after each execution `mpirun -n 3 ./a.out` while the correct one is 3. Why is that so?

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int* a;
    MPI_Win win;
    MPI_Win_allocate(size*sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &a, &win);

    int one = 1;
    int target_proc = 0;
    int shift = target_proc;

    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, target_proc, 0, win);
    MPI_Accumulate(&one, 1, MPI_INT, target_proc, shift, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, win);
    MPI_Win_unlock(target_proc, win);

    if (rank == target_proc)
        std::cout << a[shift] << std::endl;

    MPI_Win_free(&win);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is there is a race condition in your program :
nothing guarantees that rank 0 will exit `MPI_Win_unlock()` first, second or last, and hence the different results.

A simple fix is to add

```
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

before printing `a[0]`